# after giving the transition-duration property i cant able to use the jQuery functions properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery functions like .hide(),.fadeIn(),.fadeOut() are not properly working after giving the transition duration property.

example : hide(2000) then after 2 second it is hiding but the animation is not getting applied and it is the common problem i am having with all the jQuery  functions

if i delete the transition-duration then all working with animation. Why this is happening? Someone explain it to me and also give solution to solve this problem

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Opening Sequence </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="open.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="open.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<br><br>
<section id="container">

<p id="content"> This is cool </p>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#container
{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    line-height:500px;
}
#content
{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    transition-duration:3s;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //alert("Application has been started");
    $i=0;
    var ob=$('#content');
    ob.slideUp(4000);
    //ob.hide(2000);

});
```

problem is after 4 seconds it is hiding but not sliding up, in the sense not animating like hiding from the down to the top

Comment: _"but the animation is not getting applied"_ What is "the animation" ? Can create include `html` , `css` at Question ?, create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: seems like something you are doing in CSS is interfering with the brute force javascript based animation that jQuery performs - without seeing html, css and your javascript, one can only speculate as to what you have done wrong

Comment: @JaromandaX now can you help me

Comment: @KarthiKeyan What is expected result ? What effect should setting `transition-duration` have ?

Comment: @guest271314 if i use ob.css("color","red"); then it takes transition duration but ob.hide(2000); dont need the transition duration. if already transition duration specified then it is not hiding as normal. you know .hide() function and how it works but it is simply hiding. i want to know why it is happening like that

Comment: `.hide()` is commented , `.slideUp()` hides element after four seconds if `transition-duration` is commented out. `ob.css("color","red");` does not appear at `js` at Question ?

Comment: what should be transitioned at all?! i can't see the use of "transition-duration" here.